# return не возвращает нужное значение

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Функция считает сколько раз нужно умножить цифры числа друг на друга чтобы получить одну цифру. Всё работает, но возвращаемая переменная в `console.log` равна правильному значению, а в `return` равна `undefined`. Возвращает правильно значение только если это 0.

```
function persistence(num) {
  let c = 0;

  num = `${num}`.split("");

  if (`${num}`.length > 1) {
    count++;
    num = num.reduce((a, b) => a * b);
    persistence(num);
  }
  else {
    c = count;
    count = 0;
    console.log(c);
    return c;
  }
}

let count = 0;
console.log(persistence(39));
```

Comment: Потому что в первом случае вы забыли `return persistence(num);`, вот оно и ничего не возвращает

Comment: @Darth спасибо) помогло

Comment: _Возвращает правильно значение только если это 0._ не только, судя по условию, правильно будет работать, если в `num` всего одна цифра

Comment: @Darth, ответы в ответы?